# How to convert a Vue-wrapped object to a normal object

Tags: vue.js

I need to assign the data variable of type object to a normal variable

```js
const myVue = new Vue({
  el: '#myVue',
  data: {
    vars: {}, // show Form
  },
  methods: {
    assign_vars() {
      const new_vars = this.vars;
    },
  },
});
```

html

```html
<input type="text"  v-model="vars.name" >
```

I need  `new_vars` to be just like this:

```js
new_vars: { name: 'test' }
```

but what happens is `new_vars` is having all the attributes that Vue creates

Comment: OK. And what is your question? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Like this `let new_vars = {name: this.vars.name};` ?

Comment: yes but I need it dynamically 
``` let new_vars = this.vars;```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "dynamically". Please be more specific.

Comment: Depends on your project settings but you can use object destructuring. e.g. const new_vars = { ...this.vars };

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.vars)) =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vue wraps its observed data in a special object to efficiently observe changes (this is what enables reactivity). In most use cases you won't need to unwrap the object, but in case you do, here are a couple of methods:

```js
const unwrapped = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.vars));
```

This is the method suggested by Evan You [here](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/292). It works well even for deeply nested objects, as long as the types can be converted to and from JSON (strings, numbers, booleans, objects, and arrays). If your data contains something else (e.g. dates), you'll need another approach.

```js
const unwrapped = { ...this.vars }
```

This works well for shallow objects, even if they contain non-primitives.

If you have a deeply nested object containing non-primitive values, you'll need to write a function that recursively unwraps its sub-objects.

Comment: I don't know if anyone tried to measure which method was more efficient, so I used a simple comparison model. If someone confirms it in a more appropriate way, it would be welcome. My test criterion was to compare between 3 ways I know how to convert: `Object.assign`, `JSON.stringify into JSON.parse`, `const unwrapped = { ...this.vars }`. It looping 100000 iterations, in my computer `const unwrapped = { ...this.vars }` it was much faster than the others, a total of `1462.4199999962002 ms`. The others, `5084.745000000112 ms` and `8934.004999988247 ms` respectively.

Answer (score 10):

u can use toRaw(reactive object goes here) method.

Comment: ☝️ This is what you want (https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw)

Comment: ☝️ One vote... wasn't toRaw born to do exactly what the OP asked?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep functions, `lodash.defaultsDeep({}, vm.$data)` is a good idea.